# StdClass массив

Tags: php, массивы, wcf, soap

Доброго времени суток, пишу wcf сервис и php soap клиент к нему
сервис возвращает массив `string`, но на стороне php не могу его обработать в `var_dump` пишет

```
Object(stdClass)#3 (1) { 
   ["string"]=> array(2) { 
      [0]=> string(5) "en_ru" [1]=> string(4) "bold" 
   } 
}
```

как это правильно обработать ? пробовал писать `$array->{0}` но `var_dump` показывает `NULL`

Answer (score 1):

вопрос решен  $array ->string